# How to add a horizontal in the SAME view

Tags: android

After some googling, I found that most sites / links only mention the way to create a horizontal line between two views. But what I wish to achieve now is to have a horizontal line somewhere in a scrollable text view.

Comment: Whoever voted down my question, please let me know the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not Put a Line in text view Instade You can achieve it by using two textview & divider line, May I know Where u want to use it

Comment: Let's say I have 10 stories in a list view. Each story, when clicked, will go to a new activity that contains the corresponding story. The story is displayed in a scrollable view. Since a story has a number of chapters, I need a horizontal line that acts as a separator between chapters.

Comment: you can use webview in place of Textview if you want to display static text.
and you can put horizantal line in webivew using Html <hr> tag like this

WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);

 String data=Html.fromHtml("Your Storiy1 <hr> Your Story2 ");

 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");